# retrieving cpu speed and remove } from output

Tags: powershell, cpu-speed

I'm trying to get cpu speed.

This is what I've done so far

```
$cpu = [string](get-wmiobject Win32_Processor | select name)
$($cpu.split("@")[-1]).trim()
```

and my output is

```
2.40GHz}
```

How can I remove "}" from my output without having to play with string functions?
Is there a better way to achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to try `(get-wmiobject Win32_Processor).MaxClockSpeed` if you want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PS > $p = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
PS > $p -replace '^.+@\s'
2.40GHz
```

Comment: Agreed, Shay. -expandProperty isn't well known, but this is exactly what it's good for.

Answer (score 3):

You know what ... I'am Unhappy !

Powershell gives objects ! objects contains informations, and guys you are still trying to manipulate strings

```
(get-wmiobject Win32_Processor).MaxClockSpeed
```

Gives the max CPU

After that you can give the string format you want

```
$cpuSpeed = ((get-wmiobject Win32_Processor).MaxClockSpeed)/1000
$cpuspeedstring = ("{0}Go" -f  $cpuspeed)
```

Comment: And I would still parse the string. On one of my machines, `MaxClockSpeed` is 1862, which is close enough to the "`1.86GHz`" in the `Name`. But on another, `MaxClockSpeed` is 1994, and I'd rather display "`2.00GHz`" from `Name`. If it has to be formatted to a string in the end anyway for displaying, I'd rather start with a string that's already formatted the way I want and take a chunk out of it rather than tweak an integer that's a bit *too* accurate.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` and `trim()` are string functions, by the way.

You can replace `}`:

```
$($cpu.split("@")[-1]).trim() -replace '}',''
```

**Addendum:** Here's a simpler way.

```
$cpu = (get-wmiobject Win32_Processor).name.split(' ')[-1]
```

The `}` you were seeing was an artifact produced by casting the results of `Select-Object` (which creates an object) to a `string`. Instead you just take the `name` property directly, split on the space character instead and take the last segment of the `string[]`.

Comment: +1. Hi Joel. Thanks for your quick reply. I know that split() and trim() are both string functions but it seems to me very strange all this mess to get a simple information and I hope there is a cleaner way. :)

Comment: Downvoter: I'd appreciate an explanation how my answer is either not useful or incorrect. (It can't possibly be retaliatory, eh? I've downvoted no answer here.)

Comment: Joel. Don't mind. Sometimes it happened even to me to be downvoted even for accepted answers with many votes. It's a strange world. :) Even my question has been downvoted, probably from the same guy. We'll survive the same.

Comment: @nick: I know. It's just that the lack of explanation isn't constructive. That's why we can change our vote if a post has been edited.